# Using a 'public' variable or return via a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wonder which of the following approaches is better?  It appears that they can produce the same result.  Are there any drawbacks for using any of them?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainProgram extends StatelessWidget {
  int A;

  void functionA() {
    A = 1;
  }

  int functionB() {
    var _A = 1;
    return _A;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    functionA();
    var resultA = A;
    var resultB = functionB();
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [Text(resultA.toString()), Text(resultB.toString())],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If your variable is going to be the one which is resettable, it's better to use `functionA()`. `var resultA = A` is good for casting away nullability (but not limited to) if your variable was declared nullable. And third case is mentioned by me in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no drawbacks of one over the other, it all boils down to what you're going to do. In this particular case I'd suggest you to use

```dart
int functionB() {
  var foo = some_work;
  return foo;
}
```

```dart
var b = functionB();
```

Comment: that being said, a good general rule to follow is to keep your scope as small as possible.